# BorderThickness of Border control doesn't work

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have defined the following DataTemplate:

```
                    <dxg:TableView.DataRowTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Border BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="#D0C9A0" Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}">
                                <dx:MeasurePixelSnapper>
                                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{Binding View.DefaultDataRowTemplate}"/>
                                </dx:MeasurePixelSnapper>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:TableView.DataRowTemplate>
```

And I want to apply this style when the row is focused:

```
        <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="borderStyle">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="dxg:GridViewBase.IsFocusedRow" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Why doesn't it work? I don't understand why the Trigger is noct executed. Any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The local property value set by `<Border BorderThickness="0" ...>` has higher precedence than any value set by a Style. Hence the value set by the Trigger is silently ignored.

Just remove the BorderThickness assignment:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#D0C9A0" Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}">
    ...
</Border>
```

See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).